# JBoss EAP 6.4/7 - Spring Boot Application's internal log4j2.xml configuration not printing on console

Tags: jboss, spring-boot, slf4j, log4j2, jboss-eap-6

I have looked up similar questions but none of the answers really fixed the problem. I have a Spring Boot application configured to use slf4j+log4j2 (with an internal log4j2.xml config in `src/main/resources`). I deploy this war on JBoss EAP (6.4 & 7) and can see log traces from JBoss startup. The problem is that **log4j2 appenders just don't print anything, neither on console nor on the file**:

- In the console only the jboss logging logs show up (**every log.info() in my appplication traces with jboss logging format**).
- A `c:\logs\out.log` **file is created but nothing is written on it**.

These are the things I have done:

1. I have debugged and checked that Spring Boot's `Log4J2LoggingSystem` is correctecty initialized with the `classpath:log4j2.xml` file.
2. My application is using SLF4J and while debugging I have seen that the underlying logging implementation is JBoss' logging instead of Log4j2
3. The log4j2 logging works correctly on Tomcat.
4. In standalone.xml I have removed `<extension module="org.jboss.as.logging"/>` and the `<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:3.0">` block. After doing this, only a few jboss traces are printed on the console (but nothing from the application log.info()),  but the log4j2 file appender prints correctly.

How can in configure JBoss to support the application's log4j2.xml printing on the console and a file?

**log4j2.xml excerpt**:

```
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout ...
        <RollingFile name="file"
            filePattern="'.'%d{yyyy-MM-dd}"
            fileName="c:\logs\out.log">
            <PatternLayout
                pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS} - %c{1.} %5p - %m%n" />
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>
    <Logger name="org.springframework" level="info" additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="file" />
        <AppenderRef ref="console" />
    </Logger>
</Configuration>
```

**UPDATE**

The problem has to do with the way JBoss manages SLF4J:

```
org.slf4j.Logger slf4jLogger = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(PresupuestoController.class);
org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger log4j2Logger = LogManager.getLogger(PresupuestoController.class);
```

If I run `slf4jLogger.info("SLF4J!!!");`. It prints with the underlying JBoss Logger:

```
11:19:03,122 INFO  [com.my.web.SomeController] (default task-2) SLF4J!!!
```

but when I execute `log4j2Logger.info("LOG4J2!!!");` it prints on the console following my log4j2.xml configuration:

```
11:19:03,668 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2) 2016-05-19T11:19:03.663  c.m.w.SomeController  INFO - LOG4J2!!!
```

As as requirement I have to use SFL4J in the code so I need a way to force it to use Log4j2 instead of JBoss.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After struggling with this, here is what finally worked it out: adding a`jboss-deployment-structure.xml` file to my WEB-INF folder with this content:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name='org.slf4j' />
            <module name='org.slf4j.impl' />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Now JBoss logging keeps working but also allows me to use SFL4J + Log4j2 in my app code.

Comment: Did not work for me in JBoss AS 7.1. Are you sure the above is the only thing to do? Haven't you missed additional steps?

Answer (score 3):

For an EAR application (Spring MVC), I had to put this jboss-deployment-structure.xml in META-INF:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>  
      <exclude-subsystems>  
          <subsystem name="logging"/>  
      </exclude-subsystems>  
    </deployment> 
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
   <deployment>
      <exclusions>
         <module name="org.apache.commons.logging" />
         <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
         <module name="org.jboss.logging" />
         <module name="org.jboss.logging.jul-to-slf4j-stub" />
         <module name="org.jboss.logmanager" />
         <module name="org.jboss.logmanager.log4j" />
         <module name="org.slf4j" />
         <module name="org.slf4j.impl" />
      </exclusions> 
   </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had a hard time getting log4j2 working on JBoss 6.

If you're running a web app, rather put the xml config file under src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/log4j2.xml

Also make sure you've got the correct dependencies, and obviously, since you're set at 'WARN', that you're logging WARN/ERROR level at least.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, I just updated the question, it seems to be something related to SFL4J...